# Ionic 2 with promise doesn’t refresh the view correctly

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

It seems that the application doesn't refresh for some reason until the next action (click on a button for the second time for instance).

For example:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SqlStorage} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/authenticate/authenticate.html'
})
export class AuthenticatePage {
  private username: string;
  private storage: SqlStorage = null;
  private usernameTemp: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  saveCredentials(){
    this.storage = new SqlStorage();
    this.storage.set("username", JSON.stringify(this.username));
  }

  showCredentials(){
    let sqlStorage = new SqlStorage();
    sqlStorage.get('username').then((data) => {
      if (data != null){
        this.usernameTemp = JSON.parse(data);
      } else{
        this.usernameTemp = 'fail';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

One click that will trigger the showCredentials() function won't show usernameTemp on screen if the screen has a {{usernameTemp}} section until the second time it is clicked.
It always shows the former value - if you write something and saves it using saveCredentials(), then call showCredentials() then change the value and call saveCredentials(), then call showCredentials() again - you will see the first username, not the second.

Is it possible that happens only to me?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Nimrod.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your promise is running outside Angular Zone that listens for changes. Try importing NgZone, pass it to your constructor as a parameter and wrapping your promise inside:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Then:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  //Your promise code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing something wrong but angular2 has a particular way of change detection which you can read about here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

To fix your problem inject ChangeDetectorRef in to your constructor and when the promise is done call detectChanges from its instance. You don't have to do this everywhere but in "deep" promises like these. 
Please note that detect changes is an expensive maneuver and should be used carefully.